# Update not working using WHERE, AND, JOIN although select is

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I am once again very confused and I return here for more help

If I run the following query I return 721 records.

```
select 
users.`MobilePhone`
from users 
left join MobilePhones on 
users.`MobilePhone` = MobilePhones.`Telephone No`

WHERE MobilePhones.`Telephone No` IS NULL
and 
users.`MobilePhone` <> "" 
and 
users.`TelephonyProfile` = "Mobile"
and 
users.`MobilePhone` not like "44%"
```

I now want to flag these to be looked into further.

I therefore run the following

```
UPDATE users join MobilePhones on (users.`MobilePhone` = MobilePhones.`Telephone No`)

SET `CheckMobileNo` = 'YES' 

WHERE MobilePhones.`Telephone No` IS NULL
  and 
users.`MobilePhone` <> "" 
  and 
users.`TelephonyProfile` = "Mobile"
  and 
users.`MobilePhone` not like "44%"
```

This returns NO updates, the `CheckMobileNo` have not been updated and remain blank.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: As rule, run your update conditions as a select query before trying to update against them. If you get no results, you know you won't get any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join here:

```
UPDATE users join MobilePhones on
```

should be a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thank you Erie well spotted,  Tested and confirmed working, I am clearly in need of some sleep. Thank you, Thank you..........